# Convert a series to diagnol dataframe with all other elements as zero python pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

convert this series or dataframe in pandas python

```
1 2 3
```

to

```
1 0 0
0 2 0
0 0 3
```

how to do it in pandas way. this can be achieved by loops and something like it

Answer (score 0):

you can use numpy to do this.
the following code will work

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros((3, 3), int)
np.fill_diagonal(a, [1,2,3])

print(a)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 3]])
```

To convert it into dataframe, just do the following

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(d)

   0  1  2
0  1  0  0
1  0  2  0
2  0  0  3
```

Comment: I want to do this with dataframe and not with numpy

Comment: if you only want this with pandas, write a function and apply it using lambda